# Using Singleton in Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this sample class to test the Singleton in Swift 2.1:

```
class FGSingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = FGSingleton()

    var gameScore: Int = 0

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: "plist")
    //below line is creating issue because of using sharedInstance
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: sharedInstance.path!)

    // METHODS
    private init() {
        print(__FUNCTION__)
    }
    func displayGameScore() {
        print("\(__FUNCTION__) \(self.gameScore)")
    }
    func incrementGameScore(scoreInc: Int) {
        self.gameScore += scoreInc
    }
}
```

But when I call the func like this `FGSingleton.sharedInstance.displayGameScore()`, it never call that function neither it prints from `init`. I have tried to debug it and found that the cursor never get inside the function.

This is due to that error line which I commented above. Any idea how to call a global variable from sharedInstance to assign value to another global variable?

Comment: First of all, your code is not Swift 2.1 (`println`). Also, when I try to call `FGSingleton.sharedInstance.displayGameScore()` with your code, everything works correctly.

Comment: sorry, my typo mistake... But this sample code doesn't work from `ViewDidLoad()` function of ViewController.

Comment: I tried it also. It worked for me from `viewDidLoad()` of ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution which I found is to initialize global var as optional and then assign it a value from another global var inside `init()`. Here is my updated code:

```
class FGSingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = FGSingleton()

    var gameScore: Int = 0

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: "plist")
    //initialize as optional
    let dict: NSDictionary?

    // METHODS
    private init() {
        print(__FUNCTION__)
        dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: self.path!)
    }
    func displayGameScore() {
        print("\(__FUNCTION__) \(self.gameScore)")
    }
    func incrementGameScore(scoreInc: Int) {
        self.gameScore += scoreInc
    }
}
```

If there is any other better solution then let me know.